# Need an alternative method for rotating images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, cgpoint, uiimageorientation

I have a method implementation that works perfectly for rotating images. The only problem is that it has been causing memory warnings in the console and has been causing my app to crash due to memory pressure.

I need to find a new method that will achieve the same results, but not cause memory issues or app crashes.

Here is the method implementation that I am using right now:

```
-(UIImage*) rotate:(UIImage*) src andOrientation:(UIImageOrientation)orientation

{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(src.size);

    CGContextRef context=(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

      if (orientation == UIImageOrientationRight) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI) ;
       } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationLeft) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, -90/180*M_PI);
       } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationDown) {
        // NOTHING
       } else if (orientation == UIImageOrientationUp) {
        CGContextRotateCTM (context, 90/180*M_PI);
        }


    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];



    UIImage *img=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;

}
```

The specific statement that causes 90% of the memory problem is:

```
    [src drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

So a solution could be a replacement for that statement, or an entirely new method implementation.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I use the same exact code in a app with allot if images and have no memory warnings, are you sure your releasing your images after you use them?

Comment: When I want to "release" my images, I just set them to "nil". Is that correct, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Look at the Debug Navigator and watch the memory.  Does it increase every time you rotate an image?  If so, you definitely have a memory leak.

Comment: @NealEhardt Yes. I just tested it and whenever it is rotating the memory jumps up to 70 MB+ and after taking 3-5 images it crashes.

Comment: Call UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() and store it in a CGContextRef variable. Use this variable in your functions, not a new call to get a context. Then, when you are finished drawing, call CGContextRelease()

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to objective-c and not really sure how I would implement the changes you just described.